# Using Glide.js in custom Gutenberg block

Tags: plugins, block-editor, post-editor

I'm in the process of building a custom slider Gutenberg block that incorporates the use of `InnerBlocks`. I've chosen to implement this slider using [Glide.js](https://glidejs.com/). Below is a demo video showcasing the custom block, **which functions perfectly in the post editor**:

However, **I'm encountering an issue when attempting to use the same block within the site editor**. The error encountered is illustrated by the following images:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

Here is the code for the `Edit` component of the custom block:

```js
/**
 * External dependencies
 */
import Glide from '@glidejs/glide';
import { useEffect, useRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import { useSelect } from '@wordpress/data';
import {
    InnerBlocks,
    useBlockProps,
    useInnerBlocksProps,
} from '@wordpress/block-editor';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Controls from './controls';
import './editor.scss';

/**
 * Edit function for the block.
 *
 * @param {Object}   props               The props.
 * @param {Object}   props.attributes    The block attributes.
 * @param {Function} props.setAttributes The function to set attributes.
 * @param {string}   props.clientId      The block client ID.
 *
 * @return {WPElement} The edit component.
 */
export default function Edit( { attributes, setAttributes, clientId } ) {
    const sliderRef = useRef();
    const sliderEl = useRef();

    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    const { children, ...innerBlocksProps } = useInnerBlocksProps(
        { className: 'glide__slides' },
        {
            renderAppender: InnerBlocks.ButtonBlockAppender,
            templateLock: attributes.templateLock && 'all',
        },
    );

    // Get total number of slide count.
    const { blockCount } = useSelect( ( select ) => ( {
        blockCount: select( 'core/block-editor' ).getBlockCount( clientId ),
    } ) );

    // Update the number of slides when the block count changes.
    useEffect( () => {
        setAttributes( { slideCount: blockCount } );
    }, [ blockCount, setAttributes ] );

    // Initialize the slider.
    useEffect( () => {
        const {
            perView,
            gap,
            hoverPause: hoverpause,
            animationDuration,
            controls,
        } = attributes;

        const slider = new Glide( sliderEl.current, {
            type: 'slider',
            perView,
            gap,
            autoplay: false, // Autoplay is disabled in editor.
            hoverpause,
            animationDuration,
            controls,
            keyboard: false, // Keyboard navigation is disabled in editor.
        } );

        slider.mount();

        if ( ! sliderRef.current ) {
            sliderRef.current = slider;
        }

        return () => slider.destroy();
    }, [] ); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

    // Update the slider when attributes change.
    useEffect( () => {
        if ( ! sliderRef.current ) {
            return;
        }

        const {
            perView,
            gap,
            hoverPause: hoverpause,
            animationDuration,
            controls,
        } = attributes;

        sliderRef.current.update( {
            perView,
            gap,
            hoverpause,
            animationDuration,
            controls,
        } );
    }, [ children, attributes ] );

    return (
        <>
            <Controls
                { ...{
                    attributes,
                    setAttributes,
                    nextSlide: () => sliderRef.current.go( '>' ),
                    prevSlide: () => sliderRef.current.go( '<' ),
                } }
            />
            <div { ...blockProps }>
                <div className="glide" ref={ sliderEl }>
                    <div className="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                        <div { ...innerBlocksProps }>{ children }</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```